# Linked list with queue LNK2005 error

Tags: c++, linked-list, queue

Hello I wrote the following program (queue with linkedlist) but I have an error I can not figure out how to fix it I would be happy if you help me fix it.

This is the code for my problem and i get 3 errors:

> Error   1   error LNK2005: "struct Node * rear" (?rear@@3PAUNode@@A) already defined in main.obj
>   Error   2   error LNK2005: "struct Node * front" (?front@@3PAUNode@@A) already defined in main.obj
>   Error   3   error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

Code -

queue.h

```
#ifndef _MYQUEUE_H
#define _MYQUEUE_H
#include <iostream>

struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node* next;
} *rear, *front;


void enqueue(int element);
void dequeue();

#endif
```

main

```
#include <iostream>
#include "myQueue.h"

int main()
{
    Node *rear;
    Node *front;

    enqueue(7);
    enqueue(4);
    enqueue(9);

    dequeue();
    dequeue();
    dequeue();

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

queue.cpp

```
#include "myQueue.h"

void enqueue(int element)
{
    Node* temp = new Node;
    temp->data = element;
    temp->next = NULL;

    if (front == NULL)
    {
        front = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        rear->next = temp;
    }
    rear = temp;
}

void dequeue()
{
    Node* temp = new Node;
    if (front == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "No elements" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        temp = front;
        front = front->next;
        std::cout << temp << std::endl;
        delete temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two declaration of `rear` and `front` pointer

One in queue.h and other in main

Remove `rear` and `front` pointer from main

```
int main()
{
   //Node *rear;
   //Node *front;
   .....
}
```

Have `extern Node *rear, *front;` in queue.h and define those in queue.cpp

```
Node *rear, *front;
```

Comment: @user3742037 what doesn't work ? Did it say something different now ?

Comment: @user3742037 No it shouldn't, you did follow what I wrote, it works at my end. Make sure you have `struct Node { int data;Node* next;} ;extern Node* rear, *front ;` in queue.h `Node *rear, *front;` at top in queue.cpp and comment out `front` and `rear` from main